# How to get list of individuals who broke the build in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is there a way to retrieve a list of *individuals who broke the build* in Jenkins Pipeline, just like the mailer plugin apparently does to send out a mail to those involved?

Answer (score 1):

I've found one possible way, though it is somewhat limited to the amount of builds that are being kept. By iterating over the `previousBuild` hierarchy and their change logs, this may be a solution:

```groovy
def getAuthors(def build) {
    def userIds = []

    build.changeSets.each { hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogSet changeLogSet ->
        userIds += changeLogSet.collect { it.author.id }
    }

    userIds.unique()
}

def getIndividualsWhoBrokeTheBuild() {
    def userIds = []

    for(def build = currentBuild; build.result != 'SUCCESS'; build = build.previousBuild) {
        userIds += getAuthors(build)
    }

    userIds.unique()
}
```

Suppose a job keeps only five builds, this won't return the original felon, if it was broken more than five builds before.

Comment: Sure, if you delete data, you can't access it anymore ;-)

Comment: Yes, but the mailer-plugin somehow tracks the original committer without that limitation, does it?